# Datepicker not showing days - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm struggling with the answer to this, the reason I'm struggling is because the datepicker is working on one of my pages.

Could an issue be that i'm loading a datatable at the same time as the datepicker? Because on the broken page, i'm loading the datatable which uses the date from the datepicker.

**Problem reproduced**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dvsy7uu/8/) - Without including the FilterLoggingTable function, it works fine.

**Code snippet for Datepicker**

```
if (typeof $('#generateDate, #loggingDatePicker').datepicker !== 'undefined')
{
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $('#generateDate, #loggingDatePicker').datepicker(
    {
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        autoclose: false
    });
    $('#generateDate, #loggingDatePicker').datepicker('setValue', currentDate).datepicker('update').datepicker();

}
```

**HTML (Broken Datepicker)**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group date col-md-3 pull-right" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-04-2015">                        
    <input id="loggingDatePicker" class="form-control" type="text" value="12-04-2015" size="14" />
       <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML (Working Datepicker)**

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
   <div class="input-group date " data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-04-2015">                        
   <input id="generateDate" class="form-control generatePDFBTNS" type="text" value="12-04-2015" size="14" />
     <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Broken Page**

[image]

**Working Page**

[image]

Comment: Can you create a problem fiddle??

Comment: did you include jqueryui on the page with the 'broken' html? because it works fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjbswqL8/

Comment: I've added a fiddle @GuruprasadRao

Comment: I've reproduced in fiddle - @JeremyC.

Comment: why you have `autoclose:false` in datepicker

Comment: `autoclose:false`, doesn't actually do anything. I can remove that line, but it also doesn't fix the problem @GuruprasadRao

Comment: It will fix the problem -> See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9dvsy7uu/10/)** You are refreshing the `dataTable` on date change which will effect your `datepicker` in some action. Unsure what!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao In your fiddle, when you select a new day. The problem occurs again

Comment: That's again because of your `dataTable` takes time to refresh as you have `setTimeout` and if you wait until it loads then will not break. So I can say problem is with your refresh function!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Do you know any idea to improve this?

Comment: Tell me one thing. Why are you using `setTimeout`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `setTimeout` is no longer in my code, I've removed that now and updated it in my Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9dvsy7uu/14/)**

Ok. The problem was with your below line:

`("tr:not(:has(>th))").show().filter`

inside `FilterLoggingTable()` function.

> **What this does is hides or shows all the `tr`s in the page when criteria is matched!Now why**
>   **this effects your calendar is because the bootstrap creates `table`**
>   **for your `calendar` when you initialize the `datepicker` and that**
>   **table will also match the above criteria which should be only there**
>   **for `dataTables`.**

So, what you need to do is just get the `tr`s of `dataTable` as below:

```
$('#dataTables-example').find("tr:not(:has(>th))").show().filter(function ()
```

Now you can keep `autoclose:false` if you want..